# Facebook Login for app. Should I be logging in every time the app is launched?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the `Facebook Login Button` for authentication and login for my app.

After logging in the first time to Facebook, do most apps require to keep logging into Facebook after the first time (each time they return to the app)? Or should the app just save the info received from the first time login: fbId, full name, etc?

What is considered best practice for apps that authenticate users with Facebook?

My main concern is what happens if the `Facebook Login API` goes down one day. I wouldn't want my users to not be able to enter the app for that reason.

How would you guys tackle this?